# Getting the current selected item in Command Console using GUI extension commands

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, cme, gui-extensions

I am able to get the currently selected folder in CME using:
$models.getNavigator().properties.contextUri;

Below is the output:

[image]

However, I am unable to get the currently selected item in right pane. As seen in above screenshot, the item : "BrandCalippo" is selected.

I have checked the properties object of `$models.getNavigator().properties` but cannot find any relevant key to get the selected item.

Is it possible to get the URI of currently selected item similar to the way ContextUri is read as above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't how you are *supposed* to get the selected items.

The recommended approach is to create a command for your feature, which will then get called with the selection of items -- either from the tree, the list, the item editing screen, or some other context.

The idea is that your command should work regardless of the UI controls that might use it. It should be decoupled from the inner workings of those controls.

So, for instance, if you add an option to the context menu you then also specify the command that the option uses. The `IsEnabled` and `IsAvailable` methods will then get called automatically when the selection changes (regardless of context) and should return `true` if the command is available / enabled based on that selection of items.

The context menu option will then hide itself (if `IsAvailable` returns `false`) or disable itself (if `IsEnabled` returns `false`) -- or the opposite, depending on your code. When the user clicks on the context menu option, the `Execute` method will be called on your command. You can then do *whatever it is* you wish to do on that selection of items.

Comment: This is probably a good tutorial to follow when learning UI extensions: http://www.curlette.com/?p=913 - it was written for 2011, but most should work as is.

Comment: See also https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/AnguillaSnippets